# Анимация ожидания при переходе на другую активити

Tags: android, java

Как можно сделать анимацию ожидания при переходе на другую активити? Весь экран белый и только кружок по центру, что-то подобное.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) делаем корневым элементом леяута нужной активити `FrameLayout`.  
2) в него добавляем 2 чайлда. Первый - леяут самой активити, который должен там быть; второй - еще один `FrameLayout`, в который кладем `ProgressBar`, и делаем ему `background="#ffffff"`(белый бегграунд).  
3) выставляем у второго `FrameLayout` `visibility="gone"`  
4) выставляем у второго `FrameLayout` `android:id="@+id/loading"`(например)  
5) когда надо показать анимацию ожидания, делаем `findViewById(R.id.loading).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`  
когда надо спрятать - `findViewById(R.id.loading).setVisibility(View.GONE);`

Comment: Спасибо большое, очень понятно пояснили, 
подскажите, как мне поступить: у меня в активити запускаю фрагмент, а во фрагменте происходят тяжелые вычисления, как мне можно запустить это фрагмент в другой поток, чтобы потом подставить. 

    findViewById(R.id.loading).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Handler h = new Handler() {
....

    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
....

    t.start();
        Fragment comp  = new ComputeBest();
        fTrans = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fTrans.add(R.id.RelativeLayout1, comp);
            fTrans.commit();

Comment: @eldqs, совсем непонятно, чего вы хотите достичь...

Comment: @metalurgus это код из активити, ComputeBest это фрагмент, который надо вставить в лайоут, хочу запустить это фрагмент в отдельном потоке(потому как там долгие вычисления идут) а пока пользователю будет показываться прогресс бар, а когда во фрагменте завершится вычисление я готово буду убрать прогресс бар, у меня не получается все это сделать в одном потоке, это, наверное, невозможно.

Comment: Фрагмент нельзя выполнить в потоке. Его вообще нельзя выполнить. Выполнять можно только методы. И для начала, перед тем, как начинать писать на Java, неплохо научиться писать на русском.